# Counting number of labeled features in viewed screen of ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling

I'm working in ArcGIS and I'm developing some new models which relate to labeling and now I'm testing their results.

Now I want ArcGIS to give me a count of the labelled features within the current extent view. How can I do that ? How can I determine the number of labeled features in the viewed screen? I don't want to count them manually.

Plus I want ArcMap to give statistical information about the labelled fields, let's say give me a count of the features in class 1 that were labelled in the current extent view ... etc . The more information I can get the more I can test my model.

Can anyone help me with this one ?

Comment: If you are asking about ArcGIS for Desktop I might be able to help but I would need you to [edit] your question to take GeoServer out of the equation, so that I can get a better picture of precisely what you are doing and where you are stuck.

Comment: "ArcGIS and Geoserver" makes this *two* questions

Comment: Rigging a test harness is usually 50% more work than my actual coding effort.  This question demonstrates the issue.  ArcGIS is not going to report the number of features within a rectangle unless you execute a query.  You can use that same query to compile statistics manually, or use a statistical tool, to which you would need to provide the spatial query subset.

Comment: how can i do that mr. @Vince . i would want to execute this statistical tool if it is possible to do

Comment: I would compile my own statistics; using [Summary Statistics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/summary-statistics.htm) from Python isn't going to decrease your test harness effort.

Answer (score 3):

The approach that I would try for this is to convert the labels to annotation.

In the [Converting labels to annotation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/map/working-with-text/converting-labels-to-annotation.htm) help it says:

> To convert labels within a certain extent only, zoom to the extent
>   containing the labels.

Once you have used Get Count to count them you can then delete that temporary annotation feature class ready for the next change of extent, where you repeat this step.

Comment: im sorry @PolyGeo .. the tool didnt work with annotations. more to that the tool only works with raster data

Comment: @WasimShoman Which tool only works with raster data?

Comment: the get count tool. plus i need statistics about the annotation .. i need  a tool to be used in the extent preview but using the original attribute table.

Comment: I only ever use Get Count with vector data.